# CSS3 Gradients from Webkit to Moz

Tags: css

I have this webkit gradient and need it to work on Moz Firefox.

Does anyone know of a tool of how to convert it?

Here is the webkit gradient:

```css
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #717172),
        color-stop(0.5, #3a3a3a),
        color-stop(0.51, #0d0d0f),
        color-stop(1, #0f0f10)
    );
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the best tool for this:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```css
background: #717172; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #717172 0%, #3a3a3a 50%, #0d0d0f 51%, #0f0f10 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#717172), color-stop(50%,#3a3a3a), color-stop(51%,#0d0d0f), color-stop(100%,#0f0f10)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #717172 0%,#3a3a3a 50%,#0d0d0f 51%,#0f0f10 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #717172 0%,#3a3a3a 50%,#0d0d0f 51%,#0f0f10 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #717172 0%,#3a3a3a 50%,#0d0d0f 51%,#0f0f10 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#717172', endColorstr='#0f0f10',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top bottom, #717172 0%,#3a3a3a 50%,#0d0d0f 51%,#0f0f10 100%); /* W3C (Firefox 16+) */
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [this will be helpful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_gradients)
hint -> -moz-linear-gradient